# Edit mode button

Tags: javascript, xpages

I've been thrashing around this issue for the past 2 days. I have an xPage view. I click on a link/doc, it takes me to the document in read mode. I want to have an "Edit" button at the top of that document to take me into read mode. I've looked around and found a command to do so.

I create a button. In the `onClick` event of the button, I make a line of server-sided code;

```
context.setDocumentMode("edit");
```

I save the form, go back to the view, click on the doclink, and now the document immediately comes up in edit mode. Its as if opening the doc executes the `onClick` event of this button. I want it to wait until I ACTUALLY press the button.

If I remove the button, then the doc comes up in read-mode.

To make sure something wasn't whacked, I made a REAL simple database with one form called test. One field in the form, a view called testview, then created 2 documents with the form. Created an xPage
called `xTestview` using testview and an xPage form called `xTestForm` with the button and the field. Can't get much simpler than that. Happens exactly the same there too.

Comment: That's probably issue of code in client side event - it is SSJS supposed to compute resulting CSJS.

Comment: Show us the code for your button. Sounds like something is wrong with the event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple edit button that you can use instead:

```
<xp:button value="Edit" id="edit" rendered="#{javascript:!document.isEditable()}">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="edit"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik! You've given me something to look up. I've not run across that command yet.